# Extract consecutive two pages from a pdf document and save each file with a text from each first page as the filenames

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pypdf, python-pdfreader

I have a 100 page pdf document. Each two pages contain unique employee data. I need a python code to extract each of the two pages and save them as separate files with filenames as the text extracted from each first page.
For example

- The 100 page pdf document will be saved at 50 separate files
- The first page of each file contains the text Dear Miles Wood, Dear Kate Aaron etc,
- The first extracted filename should be Miles_Wood.pdf and second Kate_Aaron.pdf and so on..

Will be most pleased with a python solution

Thanks in advance

I have tried to adapt a seemingly similar python solution by the following but it doesn't appear to work for me

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import re
import argparse
import os
 
cwd = os.getcwd()
output_dir = os.path.join(cwd, 'output')
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
 
def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--pdf", dest="pdf", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--count", dest="count", type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--regex", dest="regex", required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()
 
def split_pdf(file, page_count, regex):
    reader = PdfReader(file)
    os.chdir(output_dir)
    for i in range(0, reader.numPages, page_count):
        writer = PdfWriter()
        if reader.numPages > 1 :
            for y in range(page_count):
                writer.add_page(reader.pages[i])
                writer.add_page(reader.pages[i + y])
        else :
            writer.add_page(reader.pages[i])
        text = reader.pages[i].extract_text()
        search = re.search(regex, text)
        newname = search.group(1) + ".pdf"
        outputStream = open(newname, "wb")
        writer.write(outputStream)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    arguments = get_arguments()
    split_pdf(arguments.pdf, arguments.count, arguments.regex)](https://stackoverflow.com)

Credit https://pastebin.com/mDRV77pp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/):

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
i = 0
while i < len(doc):
    page = doc[i]
    words = page.get_text("words", sort=True)
    for k, word in enumerate(words):
        if word[4] != "Dear":
            continue
        j = k + 2  # 1st name (skipped "Mr.", "Mrs." etc.)
        # append name components until one ends with a comma
        names = [words[j][4]]
        while not words[j][4].endswith(","):
            j += 1
            names.append(words[j][4])
        filename = "-".join(names)[:-1] + ".pdf"
    new = fitz.open()
    new.insert_pdf(doc, from_page=i, to_page=i + 1)
    new.ez_save(filename)
    new.close()
    i += 2
```

Whole thing works on the assumption, that the greeting contains "Dear", then a Mr./Mrs./Ms. or whatever honorifics, then however number of names the last one ending with a comma.
We are extracting the words of the odd pages in word format and sort them (just to be sure) by y, then by x coordinate.

Comment: This is a pretty good start. When I ran it with the sorting, it didn't yield the desired result. But when I set the sorting to false and set j=k+1, it produced the expected filenames. This is because, the greetings has no honorifics. But I noticed it fails where the greetings has space before the comma and a few duplicated names. Is there a way to include an error trap or skip and go to the next iteration? Thanks for the great effort.

Comment: added a tuple on the .endswith((",", " '")) and got the typo with comma placement sorted. Thanks